# Codecept_absolute_path () not found error when executing the mftf run:test command in Magento 2.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have Magento 2.3 and I want to use Magento Functional Testing Framework version 2.3 but when I run the command `vendor/bin/mftf run:test AdminLoginTest` to run the test, the following error occurs:

```
==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Codeception\Lib\codecept_absolute_path() in /Users/hanhan/Deskto
p/workspace/magento2/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/ParamsLoader.php:25
```

In the file PramsLoader.php, `codecept_absolute_path()` method is invoked and it gives the error because this method is not defined

```
$this->paramsFile = codecept_absolute_path($paramStorage);
```

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to encounter the same error today. It's because there is an old vendor directory in dev/tests/acceptance where previously we store composer.json file and now moved to root. Deleting dev/tests/acceptance/vendor folder resolve the fatal error.